# Expansion of $(\sum x_i)^n$ in Schur polynomials

Tags: combinatorics, multivariate-polynomial

I have implemented the Schur polynomials in a computer, following two different methods.

I was intrigued by this claim from an article:

[image]

I find this paragraph a bit unclear. I'm not sure whether it means that the equality 
$$
\sum_{\lambda, |\lambda|=n} s_\lambda(x) = (\sum x_i)^n \tag{$\star$}
$$
holds for the Schur polynomials $s_\lambda$ (I know it holds for the zonal polynomials).

So I checked. I observed that, one indeed has

$$
\sum_{\lambda, |\lambda|=2} s_\lambda(x) = s_{(2)}(x) + s_{(1,1)}(x) = (\sum x_i)^2
$$
but one has
$$
s_{(3)}(x) + {\Large\color{red}{2}}s_{(2,1)}(x) + s_{(1,1,1)}(x) = (\sum x_i)^3.
$$

Are these relations correct (so $(\star)$ is wrong)? And if so, is there a general relation of the form 
$$
\sum_{\lambda, |\lambda|=n} c_\lambda s_\lambda(x) = (\sum x_i)^n
$$
for some coefficients $c_\lambda$ which have a simple expression?

Comment: If I recall correctly, $c_\lambda$ is the number of standard young tableaux with shape $\lambda$, which has a simple expression via the hook length formula.

Comment: @MikeEarnest is right. I suspect the author said "normalized" meaning  "not the usual Schur function, but rather an appropriate scalar multiple thereof".

Comment: You're right @MikeEarnest. I have an implementation of the number of SYT and I have just checked, this works. Thanks ! (maybe you could write an answer).